# Double free() or corruption:C++

Tags: c++

Why if I write a code like this (**X** is  a generic class) calling constructor and destructor

```
    int main()
      {
      X one ();
      one.~X();   
      return 0;
      }
```

give me this error?

```
Double free() or corruption:C++
```

Comment: You don't need to call the destructors manually like that. Local objects are automatically deleted at the end of the scope: `{ Y background(3000,5000); }` deletes the object at the `}`.

Comment: _@Tarlo_x_ Stop hampering around with raw pointers. Use standard containers instead.

Comment: you have to respect the way c++ handles memory for you

Comment: Your constructor should set those pointers to null, and your destructor should only delete them if non-null, then set them to null....the instructor is probably trying to highlight safe pointer handling.

Comment: @RamblinRose Note that `delete nullptr;` is fine and transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost never call destructors explicitly, they are called implicitly when an object falls out of scope (or `delete`d, if allocated on heap). First you manually deallocate `background`'s array by calling `background.~Y()`, and next this same array tries to get deallocated once more at the next `}`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the destructor of an object is almost always wrong. Actually I never came across a situation where this was right. You need to read about RAII and maybe this example will help you to understand why you get the error:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{
    Foo()  { std::cout << " constructor " << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << " destructor  " << std::endl; }
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    // foo.~Foo();  // <- never ever do this !
}                   // <- object is destroyed here !
```

Run this and you will see, that the destructor is called already. Destroying an already destroyed object leads to the error you get.